# upload multiple images from multiple form field or multiple input type in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="img1" />
  <input type="file" name="img2" />
  <input type="file" name="img3" />
</form>
```

How can i upload all the images from different form field in node js

Answer (score 0):

Here is form...

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="img1" />
  <input type="file" name="img2" />
  <input type="file" name="img3" />
</form>
```

You need to install multer npm package for file upload

```
npm i --save multer
```

After you need to require this package

```
const multer  = require('multer')

var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'img1', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'img2', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'img3', maxCount: 1 }])
app.post('/profile', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is an object (String -> Array) where fieldname is the key, and the value is array of files
  //
  // e.g.
  //  req.files['img1'][0] -> File
  //  req.files['img2'] -> Array
  //
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: You can also increase maxCount for multiple image upload for each file type